# Android Eclipse Java debugging issue about recognizing null object comparison

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I've found a very strange behavior while debugging an Android application at the following code:

```
private String process(byte[] item) {
    if(item == null) {
        item = new byte[0];
    }

    //byte val = item[0];       
    //String str = "Val = " + Integer.toString(val);        
    //Log.e(TAG, str);
    [...]
    return rez;
}
```

Sometimes, while debugging, the execution steps inside the 'IF' block when 'ITEM' is a non-null variable. What's worse is that Eclipse's Expressions view actually lists 'ITEM' as non-null, allocated variable, and 'item == null' as false. This seems to happen as long as the commented lines stay commented, and it happens both on the sim and the device.

Any ideas what is going on ?

I am using Eclipse 3.7.1, latest Android SDK, and various 1.6+ sims and 2.1+ devices.

Comment: Can you verify this with some logging in the if block? Maybe it is just some optimization thing. Also, your commented code will not work if you get into the if block, as item[0] will give you an OutOfBoundsException

Comment: I've added a log line before the 'if' and inside the 'if' block. You will never guess what now happens. I start at a breakpoint before this current function is called. I press F5 to step in, then F6 to step over each instruction inside the function. After the debugger pointing 3 times at the first line, at the fourth press of F6 it immediately moves at the last line, the return. There are other function calls that do not depend on the null state after the quoted lines. The debugger just skips them. I've tried cleaning project, rebuilding, restarting eclipse, the sim, etc. Twilight zone here...

Comment: Are you certain that you build your app in debug mode? As the method is called process, is there anything multithreaded or multiple processes going on there?

Comment: Behaves the same with DEBUG on or off. Just noticed though, that after it goes to the return line it comes back to the first line and proceeds the previously described way (failing to notice the non-null). I am at a loss at what I can try, atm. Fighting the debugger is not my idea of software development.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
if(item==null)
```

(without the spaces).
It worked for me.

*edit* the error has come back after another change in the lay-out of the program (i.e. by removing a comment)